# How to debug Android activity/view events

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am trying to write unit tests for my Android application. The particular test I'm having trouble with is just to make sure that when the user taps somewhere on my MapView, the application drops a marker where the user tapped. But everything I try leaves me with some kind of error message. Does anybody know how to write something like this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
public class MyMapActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyMapActivity> {

public MyMapActivityTest() {
    super("com.example.blah", MyMapActivity.class);
}

public void testPreconditions() {
    assertNotNull(getActivity().findViewById(com.example.blah.R.id.mapview));
}

// This method gives me the following error message: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENT permission
public void testTap1() {
    final MyMapActivity m = getActivity();
    final MapView mapView = (MapView) m.findViewById(com.example.blah.R.id.mapview);

    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    getInstrumentation().sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1, 0, 0));

    assertTrue(true);    // this doesn't execute

}

// junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Click can not be completed! Something is in the way e.g. the keyboard
public void testTap2() {
    final MyMapActivity m = getActivity();
    final MapView mapView = (MapView) m.findViewById(com.example.blah.R.id.mapview);

    // Robotium
    Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), m);
    solo.clickOnScreen(1,1);

    assertTrue(true);    // this doesn't execute
}


// This method gives me the following error message: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENT permission
public void testTap3() {
    final MyMapActivity m = getActivity();
    final MapView mapView = (MapView) m.findViewById(com.example.blah.R.id.mapview);

    TouchUtils.tapView(this, mapView);

    assertTrue(true);    // this doesn't execute
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting security exceptions,  that typically happens when you try to interact with applications that you are not allowed to interact with. A typical scenario is when the application under test opens up an Activity that is part of another application. In your Android test project (AndroidManifest.xml) you define which package you want to test. Is the MapView a part of that package?

/Renas

Comment: In the AndroidManifest.xml file for MyMapActivityTest, I have <instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.example.blah" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />. Then the class under test, <code>MyMapActivity</code> starts with "package com.example.blah". However, the MapView itself is part of the com.google.android.maps package.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm not trying to test a subclass of "android.app.Application". My program is a couple of classes that all extend "android.app.Activity". Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. You are not allowed to instrument against com.google.android.maps as that is another application. That is why you are getting the security exceptions. There is no way around it. You could resign the maps application with your certificate and make a new test project for that application but you can not use it together with your existing test project as you have stated com.example.blah as target package.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try and "touch" a child of a process other than the one under test.

In your example, I would imagine your `obtain()` method is creating a touch event which would actually interaction with the notification bar - which isn't owned by your application.

A safer way of interaction, where possible, is to use `TouchUtils.clickView()`.

I imagine in your instance you're testing the touch of a single view, so it might be worth finding the top, left, width and height of the view inside your `TestCase` before you send touch events.